# Building your own package for distribution via vcpkg

Tags: c, cmake, static-libraries, vcpkg

I'm running into an issue with a local test of (MacOS) as I install my own package from Github via `vcpkg`, in a brand new c-based project)

Here's what the `vcpkg` folder structure looks like: `x64-osx/debug` folder seems to be okay since I see the dependencies there.

### Folder Structure

- vcpkg_installed

  - vcpkg (`/info`, `/upates` etc.)
  - x64-osx

    - debug

      - include (`mylib/mylib.h` is present)
      - lib (`libmylib.a` is present)
    - include

      - mylib (`mylib.h` is present)
    - lib **(Missing libmylib.a file)**
    - share

### portfile.cmake

```
vcpkg_check_linkage(ONLY_STATIC_LIBRARY)

vcpkg_from_github(
        OUT_SOURCE_PATH SOURCE_PATH
        REPO username/mylib
        REF "${VERSION}"
        SHA512 b567c0090926e6dd6d78f5b6d839539ed517f1d133d7078bfbdc118c43edd3e354a4a045632cb64d53af06bca34041aff972700541d4131bb45d70601311af4c
        HEAD_REF main
)

vcpkg_cmake_configure(SOURCE_PATH "${SOURCE_PATH}" OPTIONS -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF)
vcpkg_cmake_install()
vcpkg_cmake_config_fixup()

file(REMOVE_RECURSE "${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR}/lib")

vcpkg_install_copyright(FILE_LIST "${SOURCE_PATH}/LICENSE")
configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/usage" "${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR}/share/${PORT}/usage" COPYONLY)
```

---

**Question**: I don't see `libmylib.a` file under the `lib` folder, and I assume a non-debug or release version has to be there for users to use this library effectively.

It seems that my vcpkg configuration (portfile.cmake) is building the debug version but not the distribution or production version.

What am I missing from my `portfile.cmake` file (that goes to the vcpkg repo) to make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not missing something your are deleting the release artifacts with:

```
file(REMOVE_RECURSE "${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR}/lib")
```

Comment: thanks, let me remove and retry that. Apart from that, do you see any issues? I'm looking for a minimalistic config.

Comment: Also, do i need this line `vcpkg_cmake_config_fixup()` ?

Comment: Is it possible to get 10-15 minute time of yours? I have been stuck on this project for about a month now, and moderators don't help me much.

Comment: `vcpkg_cmake_config_fixup()` is used to fix the install location of the cmake config files if you install any. In general you would use CONFIG_PATH here with lib/cmake/mylib if you install the cmake files there. You might also need to remove CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR/debug/share and CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR/debug/include depending on what you install. Otherwise it looks mostly fine to me. if you install *.pc files you also want to run `vcpkg_fixup_pkgconfig`

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow your comments. the project is simple, two .c files and one .h file but i have been going round and round in circles without much help. I'll post back.

Comment: As I gained more experience, I learned the lines were supposed to be 

`vcpkg_cmake_config_fixup() # removes /debug/share`
and
`file(REMOVE_RECURSE "${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR}/debug/include") # removes debug/include`

Comment: vcpkg will tell you that in the post build checks any way.